# Really weird canvas behavior with putImageData

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm struggling to draw on HTML canvas using `putImageData`.

Here is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/173mbg0n/58/

HTML:

```html
<canvas id='c'></canvas>
```

CSS:

```css
canvas {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

JavaScript:

```js
let W = 100;
let H = 100;

let c = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

let array = new Uint32Array(W * H);
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   array[i] = 0xff00ffff;

let ca = new Uint8ClampedArray(array.buffer);
let img = new ImageData(ca, W);

ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
```

Here is my result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzUxV.png

I expect all canvas to be yellow.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give the `<canvas>` element `height` and `width` attributes:

```
<canvas id='c' height=100 width=100></canvas>
```

With that change, it works. The CSS sizing of the canvas determines how the canvas looks, while the attributes of the element determine it's geometry for drawing purposes.